# Sails.js stream sql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Is there a way to stream data from `Model.query()` in sails ?

Example

```
export: (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT ...";

  let stream = Model.query(sql).stream(); // I know this does not work

  stream.pipe(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to the sails [doc](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/stream):

```
module.exports = {

  testStream: function(req, res){

    if (req.param('startStream') && req.isSocket){

        var getSocket = req.socket;

        // Start the stream.  Pipe it to sockets.
        User.stream({name:'Walter'}).pipe(getSocket.emit);

    } else {

      res.view();

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: I know that already, but it uses query object. I want to use sql query but Model::stream doesn't accept query as string parameter. I hoped someone had the same issue and found a solution.